# SelectedValue which is invalid because it does not exist in the list of items

Tags: asp.net, data-binding

I encounter this problem repeatedly, and haven't a clue what is causing it. I get an exception in the DataBind: `SelectedValue which is invalid because it does not exist in the list of items`.

Here are some important pieces of information:

1. I reload listOrgs periodically when the underlying data has changed.
2. The Organization.DTListAll call returns 2 Int, String pairs.
3. There are no duplicate or null values in the returned data
4. After the first two lines below, listOrgs.Items.Count is 0, and the Selected Value is 0
5. The selected value after the DataBind operation executes is the ID value from the first row in the data
6. This exception happens the very first time this code is executed after a fresh page load

```
listOrgs.Items.Clear(); 
listOrgs.SelectedValue = "0"; 
listOrgs.DataSource = new Organization().DTListAll(SiteID); 
listOrgs.DataTextField = "OrganizationName"; 
listOrgs.DataValueField = "OrganizationID"; 
listOrgs.DataBind();
```

Comment: At what line does the exception occur?  Informational piece #5 implies that every statement executes without an exception.

Answer (score 60):

Apparently the solution I posted wasn't entirely effective... Eventually in my application I changed to this:

```
listOrgs.Items.Clear();
listOrgs.SelectedIndex = -1;
listOrgs.SelectedValue = null;
listOrgs.ClearSelection();     // Clears the selection to avoid the exception (only one of these should be enough but in my application I needed all..)
listOrgs.DataSource = new Organization().DTListAll(SiteID);
listOrgs.DataTextField = "OrganizationName"; 
listOrgs.DataValueField = "OrganizationID"; 
listOrgs.DataBind();
```

Comment: This is the only solution that worked for me.  I never realized how horrible the stock ddl is

Comment: I made a class derived from the drop down and overrode the Set of the DataSource property to just call those things so I didn't have to remember to do it all over the place and it's working like a charm. Thanks!

Comment: It worked for me too. But I caught myself at the heretic thought "Won't it be easier to create a new instance of the DropDownList class and assign it to the same ID instead?" Sigh.

Comment: `listOrgs.Items.Clear();
listOrgs.SelectedIndex = -1;
listOrgs.SelectedValue = null;
listOrgs.ClearSelection();`
after some experimentation i was able to reduce these lines to just:
`listOrgs.Items.Clear();
listOrgs.SelectedValue = null;`
I still don't understand why one of these statements isn't enough

Comment: Hi its work for me too. I still cant get what the real cause can any one explain??

Answer (score 8):

I kept getting this error.
Weird thing is that before I set the datasource and rebind  after deleting an item  the *selected index = -1*.

If I explicitly set the `selectedIndex = -1;`  then it works and doesn't throw an error.

***So even though it was already -1  setting it to -1  stops it from erroring.***

Weird eh?

Comment: Which goes to prove the underlying insanity in the design of this control.

Comment: I had the same experience! I first did `ddl.ClearSelection()` which cleared both the selected value and index.Still I got the error. When I set `ddl.SelectedIndex = -1` and `ddl.SelectedValue = null`  explicitly however, it WORKS! ???

Comment: this is what worked for me. absolutely ridiculous. thank you

Answer (score 3):

Try setting `listOrgs.SelectedValue = "0"` after you refresh the `DataSource`

At the moment you are trying to select the first item in an empty list.

Answer (score 1):

Change the first two line with this :

```
listOrgs.SelectedItem.Selected = false; 
listOrgs.Items.Clear();
```

Comment: Setting SelectedItem.Selected = false throws an exception

Comment: What is the exception ? maybe you should instantiate your dropdownlist again before binding : listOrgs = new DropDownList();

Answer (score 1):

In case you still have this problem this is how i resolved it:

```
listOrgs.SelectedIndex = -1;    // Clears the SelectedIndex to avoid the exception
listOrgs.DataSource = new Organization().DTListAll(SiteID);
listOrgs.DataTextField = "OrganizationName"; 
listOrgs.DataValueField = "OrganizationID"; 
listOrgs.DataBind();            //Unless you have "listOrgs.AppendDataBoundItems = true" you don't need to clear the list
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure it is your case, but I had the same problem and apparently there was no explanation, then I realized doing a copy and paste on notepad of a field of database that at the beginning of the value there was a NULL.

Curious thing was that a select joining tables was working. I deleted the row and reinserted, after was working fine.

Answer (score 1):

@PMarques answer helped me out and did solve my problem.

However whilst experimenting, it clicked in my head why I was gettign the error in the first place.

I was setting the "Text" attribute thinking that it might create an encompassing label or fieldset + legend, for me (which it doesn't).

The [Text property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.listcontrol.text.aspx) for a list is infact the SelectedValue property for a ListControl.

So my mistake in misinterpreting what the text property did.

Answer (score 0):

I was getting the same error repeatedly and try ending up by not setting the default selected value to Index -1.

I commented my code `ddlDRIBidAmt.SelectedValue = -1`

This value was set at the time where my Page Controls were reset to default values.

Answer (score 0):

I know its too late to answer, but what I tried is an dirty solution but it worked.
After databinding, I am insert a item at index 0

```
ddl.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("---Select---","-1"));
```

And on setting,

I am placing try catch, In catch i am setting Value to -1